# Creating a new user using SVN command line

Tags: svn, command-line

We are using SVN on a remote server that I don't have access to.  We use TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN to check in and out for repositories.  I use SubversionEdge to log in and manage users.  I have used SlikSvn to do some command like automation for our repositories.  One thing I don't have is the ability to create users using a command line SVN tool.  I looked in all the help for the SlikSvn tool and I don't see anything.  I have looked all over and everything talks about updating a config file on the SVN server, but I don't have access to that.  Anybody know of a command line tool to add users?

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend a tool, library, book, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic here. See the numbered list of items on this [help/on-topic] page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not perform ANY **administrative-level task** using **client-level tools**